# After opening a modal other buttons do not work

Tags: javascript

After opening and closing a modal other buttons do not work (including button that opens modal) and modal doesn't open again. Maybe something is wrong in my modal code? That problem came out after adding modal js code. There are no  messages in browser console. Thanks

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-container");
var btn = document.getElementById("button-open");
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

if (btn)
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  modal[0].style.opacity = "1";
});
if (close)
close.addEventListener("click", function(){
  modal[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  modal[0].style.opacity = "0";
});
```

Comment: You set the opacity to 0, but it's still visible--you just can't see it.

Comment: Please add the css to your question, it seems that you can solve it with z-index.

Comment: Aside: if `popup-container`, `button-open`, and `close-button` are each unique elements, you should use `id=` for all of them, not just button-open — then you can use `getElementById` on all and avoid the `[0]` ... also, be consistent... `button-open` & `button-close`. Finally, if you're modifying multiple `node.style.thing` you're better off adding then removing a class, such as `popup-opened`, instead of multiple assignments to `.style`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to close the modal by making it transparent. Since it is only transparent, it still receives clicks, and blocks clicks from passing through it. You will have to find a new way to close the modal, that will prevent it from blocking click events.